# Parse QString with QXmlStreamReader

Tags: xml, qt, qxmlstreamreader

I'm trying to parse this QString that contains XML. This is the content

```
<Field_A>xxx_1</Field_A>
<Field_B>xxx_2</Field_B>
<Field_C>xxx_3</Field_C>
...
```

This XML has no root node.

This is the code that I've used to parse the XML:

```
QString xmlString = "<Field_A>xxx_1</Field_A><Field_B>xxx_2</Field_B><Field_C>xxx_3</Field_C>"

QXmlStreamReader xmlReader(xmlString);

while (!xmlReader.atEnd() && !xmlReader.hasError()) 
{
    xmlReader.readNext();

    if (xmlReader.name() == "Field_A") 
    {
        qDebug() << "Field_A: " << xmlReader.readElementText();
        continue;
    }
    
    if (xmlReader.name() == "Field_B") 
    {
        qDebug() << "Field_B: " << xmlReader.readElementText();
        continue;
    }

    if (xmlReader.name() == "Field_C") 
    {
        qDebug() << "Field_C: " << xmlReader.readElementText();
        continue;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
xxx_1
""
```

Why can't I read all node values?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a valid XML? As I have used several online parsers they tell me that it is not, just when I use `<root>
 <Field_A>xxx_1</Field_A>
 <Field_B>xxx_2</Field_B>
 <Field_C>xxx_3</Field_C>
</root>` it tells me that it is valid

Comment: XML must have a root node

Comment: Unfortunately, this is part of the message payload that I receive.